# Parsing JSON object list to array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON object that I receive from API to array using useEffect. This is JSON data that I receive:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "tmp@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$AB0WHdpP.aEpMdEg780ssej",
            "role": "student",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "tmp2@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$nhhUL.angMUh6WhyCWp33.n",
            "role": "mentor",
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the part of the code where the parsing happens:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
    }, [])


  // Fetch Users
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("Data:", data.data);
    setUsers(data.data);
    console.log("Users:", users);
  }
```

Example of Console output that i recieve:

```
Data: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1, email: 'tmp@gmai.com', password: '$2b$10$AB0WHdpP.aEpMdEg780ssej', role: 'student'}1: {id: 2, email: 'tmp2@gmail.com', password: '$2b$10$nhhUL.angMUh6WhyCWp33.n', role: 'mentor'}length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
Users: []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Any suggestion on how should this be done or what is the issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with your code.
The state updation in React is always asynchronous.

```
 setUsers(data.data);
 console.log("Users:", users);
```

Here `setUsers` will run asynchronously, hence control is moved to next line `console.log("Users:",users)` which is not yet updated and display its old value.

If you want to console.log() whenever users state changes use the following code

```
useEffect(()=> {
   console.log('Users:',users);
},[users])
```

Answer (score 1):

You see `Users` as an empty array because it is an empty array when you log it.
State update using the updater function provided by the `useState` hook is asynchronous, so the change will not be reflected immediately.

If you want to log the `users` array after state update, you can log it inside a `useEffect` hook with `users` as a dependency:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
    }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users)
    }, [users])

  // Fetch Users
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("Data:", data.data);
    setUsers(data.data);
    console.log("Users:", users);
  }
```